# How to Implement caching on apollo-server-hapi graphql

Tags: caching, graphql, hapi.js, apollo-server

i have graphql with `apollo-server-hapi`. i try to add cache control like below:

```
const graphqlOptions = {
  schema,
  tracing: true,
  cacheControl: true,
};
```

but when i try to add cache option on schema base:

```
type Author @cacheControl(maxAge: 60) {
  id: Int
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  posts: [Post]
}
```

i got this error message:

```
Error: Unknown directive "cacheControl".
```

can you help, what is the correct way to apply cache control on schema?

i follow instruction from below, but it seem didn't work.

[apollo-cache-control](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/ae9da10e625cf283568ba6d29cea8c3e69a7a03f/packages/apollo-cache-control)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After learn more about caching on apollo graphql, basically, the issue was with `makeExecutableSchema` from `apollo-server-hapi`, didn't include directive for `@cacheControl`, so to make it work, we just need to define our own `@cacheControl` directive into graphql file, as below:

```
enum CacheControlScope {
  PUBLIC
  PRIVATE
}

directive @cacheControl (
  maxAge: Int
  scope: CacheControlScope
) on FIELD_DEFINITION | OBJECT | INTERFACE

type Author @cacheControl(maxAge: 60) {
  id: Int
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  posts: [Post]
}
```

Comment: Same case with `apollo-server-lambda`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me in `"apollo-server-express": "^2.9.12"` :

1.- Set global maximum cache:

```
var graphqlServer = new ApolloServer({
  cacheControl: {
    defaultMaxAge: 1000,
  },
...
```

2.- Define the following directive in your schema:

```
// Schema (root query)
const Query = gql`
  directive @cacheControl(
      maxAge: Int,
      scope: CacheControlScope
  ) on OBJECT | FIELD | FIELD_DEFINITION

  enum CacheControlScope {
      PUBLIC
      PRIVATE
  }
  type Query {
...
```

3.- Finally, call it:

```
module.exports = `
type ArticlePage @cacheControl(maxAge: 801){
    article(id: String) : Article
    author(key: String) : Author
}`;
```

The trick is that `@cacheControl(maxAge: 801)` cannot be higher than `defaultMaxAge: 1000`.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was also `apollo-server-lambda` and the main issue comes from using `makeExecutableSchema`. The [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/caching/#defining-cache-hints) mention this is cause by schema stitching.

Unfortunately if you use something like [graphql-middleware](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-middleware) there is no way around this except for what hinduni mentions. Also make sure you are on apollo-server > 2.6.6.